# Remove everything after a certain character in a string but keep wrapped in tag

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I am iterating through multiple elements with nested text and need to remove everything after the '+' character but keep wrapped in the tag.

Current Html:

```
<div class="v-event-timed" ><div class="pl"><strong>Test Demo</strong>, 1:38 AM + 11:38 AM</div></div>
```

Desired Html Output:

```
<div class="v-event-timed" ><div class="pl"><strong>Test Demo</strong>, 1:38 AM</div></div>
```

JS - (this keeps last characters, not correct):

```
this.$el.querySelectorAll('.v-calendar .v-event-timed').forEach((div: HTMLElement, i:number, arr:NodeListOf<HTMLElement>) => {
arr[i].textContent = arr[i].textContent.replace("+", "")
})
```

JS - (this removes all tags, not correct):

```
this.$el.querySelectorAll('.v-calendar .v-event-timed').forEach((div: HTMLElement, i:number, arr:NodeListOf<HTMLElement>) => {
    arr[i].textContent = arr[i].textContent.substr(0, arr[i].textContent.lastIndexOf("+"));
    })
```

Comment: Do you have control of the HTML output? If you do you could wrap the time you want to modify in a <span> with a class and target that instead.

Comment: You are going to have to select the textNode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the child nodes, alter the text of the text node.

```js
var plChildren = document.querySelector(".pl").childNodes;
plChildren[1].textContent = plChildren[1].textContent.replace(/\s\+.*/, '');
```

```html
<div class="v-event-timed" ><div class="pl"><strong>Test Demo</strong>, 1:38 AM + 11:38 AM</div></div>
```

so for multiple

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".pl").forEach( function (elem) {
  var plChildren = elem.childNodes;
  plChildren[1].textContent = plChildren[1].textContent.replace(/\s\+.*/, '');
});
```

```html
<div class="v-event-timed" ><div class="pl"><strong>Test Demo</strong>, 1:38 AM + 11:38 AM</div></div>
<div class="v-event-timed" ><div class="pl"><strong>Test Demo</strong>, 1:38 AM + 11:38 AM</div></div>
<div class="v-event-timed" ><div class="pl"><strong>Test Demo</strong>, 1:38 AM + 11:38 AM</div></div>
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks @epascarello

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("div");
for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
  innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML;
  elements[i].innerHTML = innerHTML.substring(0, innerHTML.lastIndexOf("+"));
}
```

```html
<div class="v-event-timed" ><div class="pl"><strong>Test Demo</strong>, 1:38 AM + 11:38 AM</div></div>
```

Comment: Removes the <strong> tag, I need to keep that